# Tornado async calls in parallel from URLs in dict/list

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

I have a list of URLs which is wish to call asynchronously in parrallel in Python Tornado. Currently, this is how I go about it:

```
    response_location = yield dict(origin_maxmind=http_client.fetch(origin_urls['maxmind'], raise_error=False),
                                   origin_ipinfo=http_client.fetch(origin_urls['ipinfo'], raise_error=False),
                                   origin_freegeoip=http_client.fetch(origin_urls['freegeoip'], raise_error=False),
                                   arrival_maxmind=http_client.fetch(arrival_urls['maxmind'], raise_error=False),
                                   arrival_ipinfo=http_client.fetch(arrival_urls['ipinfo'], raise_error=False),
                                   arrival_freegeoip=http_client.fetch(arrival_urls['freegeoip'], raise_error=False))
```

Further down the road, I may want to add new URLs to call alongside those already there. I think this may be easier if the URLs are in a `dict`. Tornado would then asynchronously in parallel call all the URLs in that `dict`. Im trying to avoid having to change a lot of things if someone wants to add a new URL to call. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the urls are in one dict, it's straightforward to do this with a dictionary comprehension. To fetch all the urls in `origin_urls`, do

```
response_location = yield {name: http_client.fetch(url, raise_error=False) 
        for (name, url) in origin_urls.items()}
```

With two dicts of urls, it's a little clumsier. Here's an equivalent of the code in your question:

```
response_location = yield dict(
    [('origin_' + name, http_client.fetch(url, raise_error=False))
         for (name, url) in origin_urls.items()] +
    [('arrival_' + name, http_client.fetch(url, raise_error=False))
         for (name, url) in arrival_urls.items()])
```